# Writing elements of a vector space in vector form

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Say I am looking at $\Bbb{R}^3$ with vector space structure and I have standard basis $\{e_1,e_2,e_3\}$, then I can write a vector $ae_1+be_2+ce_3$ as:
$$\begin{bmatrix}a\\b\\c\end{bmatrix}.$$
If I have another basis $\{e_1,e_1+e_2,e_1+e_3\}=\{f_1,f_2,f_3\}$, does $af_1+bf_2+cf_3$ get written in this basis as:
$$\begin{bmatrix}a\\b\\c\end{bmatrix}$$
or as:
$$\begin{bmatrix}a+b+c\\b\\c\end{bmatrix}?$$

I find this kind of confusing since as a set $\Bbb{R}^3$ is just $\Bbb R\times\Bbb R\times \Bbb R$, so really a vector is just any element of this set. These three copies of $\Bbb R$ cannot interact under addition, so it would make sense to me to take for $\lambda_i\ne 0$, any basis of the form $\{\lambda_1e_1,\lambda_2e_2,\lambda_3e_3\}$.

Answer (score 0):

For new basis $\{e_1,e_1+e_2,e_1+e_3\}=\{f_1,f_2,f_3\}$ you should write the matrix for the vector $af_1+bf_2+cf_3$ as:
$$\begin{bmatrix}a\\b\\c\end{bmatrix}$$
because you are working on the new basis!

Answer (score 0):

It depends with respect to which basis you want to write the vector. With respect to the basis $\{f_1,f_2,f_3\}$, write $af_1+bf_2+cf_3$ as $\begin{bmatrix}a\\b\\c\end{bmatrix}$.

Since
$$af_1+bf_2+cf_3=(a+b+c)e_1+be_2+ce_3\,,$$
with respect to the basis $\{e_1,e_2,e_3\}$, we write $af_1+bf_2+cf_3$ as$\begin{bmatrix}a+b+c\\b\\c\end{bmatrix}$.

Comment: So from the set theoretic perspective, a point $(a,b,c)\in \Bbb R^3$ gets written as a different element, depending on which basis is taken? I feel that set theoretically, the point $(a,b,c)$ is well defined, independent of a basis, and then the 'vector':
$$\begin{bmatrix}a\\b\\c\end{bmatrix}$$
is not well defined, without mentioning a basis. Am I right?

Comment: If no basis is mentioned, we assume that the basis on $\mathbb{R}^n$ is the canonical basis.

Comment: I know, but any point in $\Bbb R^3$ is a 'vector' and any point has a well defined set theoretic representation right. So I guess you are saying the canonical basis agrees with the set theoretic representation.

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm saying